# jQuery bug has suddenly appeared on ALL versions of website

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a website that has some animations implemented using jQuery. All of that stuff is fine and I've finished working on that part of the site now. Somehow though, my menu that uses the [pageslide plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) has stopped working how it is supposed to. The animation still works, but instead of the menu sliding in from the left to reveal it's whole width, it is sliding in by double it's width. This is happening on all browsers and devices and definitely wasn't happening yesterday.

I'll post the code in question at the end of this post, but I actually don't think it's anything to do with any code I have. I have been using version control while building and this bug has appeared on all versions, locally & remote. So a remote site, that I haven't touched since it was working is now not.

That would suggest to me that it is not a problem with one of the files that are part of the site. However, I only have 2 external files linked to the site. The first is modernizr, and disabling that makes no difference; the second is jQuery. I've tried changing the version of jQuery to everything from just about everything from 1.10 to 2.0, still with no joy.

I'm kind of out of ideas now.

Here's the bit of pageslide.js that controls the opening of the menu:

```
// Function that controls opening of the pageslide
function _start( direction, speed ) {
    var slideWidth = $pageslide.outerWidth( true ),
        bodyAnimateIn = {},
        slideAnimateIn = {};

    // If the slide is open or opening, just ignore the call
    if( $pageslide.is(':visible') || _sliding ) return;         
    _sliding = true;

    switch( direction ) {
        case 'left':
            $pageslide.css({ left: 'auto', right: '-' + slideWidth + 'px' });
            bodyAnimateIn['margin-left'] = '-=' + slideWidth;
            slideAnimateIn['right'] = '+=' + slideWidth;
            break;
        default:
            $pageslide.css({ left: '-' + slideWidth + 'px', right: 'auto' });
            bodyAnimateIn['margin-left'] = '+=' + slideWidth;
            slideAnimateIn['left'] = '+=' + slideWidth;
            break;
    }

    // Animate the slide, and attach this slide's settings to the element
    $body.animate(bodyAnimateIn, speed);
    $pageslide.show()
              .animate(slideAnimateIn, speed, function() {
                  _sliding = false;
              });
}
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: No console error? What about 1.8/1.9 jquery version? Any website link to let us check? As i understand it, you haven't change anything, so it's quite strange.

Comment: @roasted Nope, no console error. Tried those versions too. Link is http://new.ificanapp.com/ - click the icon in the top left corner to open the menu.

Comment: On your link, i cannot see the behaviour you described. Seems to works fine. But you shouldn't link to lastest version of modernizr and jquery, i mean use script source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js & http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js . You should use specific version instead.

Comment: @roasted I've tried it on a PC, macbook and iPhone and it definitely isn't working fine. The menu is supposed to still be touching the left side of the screen when it comes out, it currently leaves a gap about the same width as the menu tab. And yeah, I usually use a specific version but was just using those for testing.

Comment: Ha ok, i see now the bug you are talking about.

Comment: @roasted It is really bizarre. It was working and now it's just not. It's wrecking my head.

Comment: Why are you declaring for #pageslide in jquery.pageslide.css position absolute and fixed? Only one should be used

Comment: @roasted Not really sure, it's part of the plugin. Definitely not anything to do with this problem though as I noticed that was there before this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem and although, as I stated I went through the various versions of jQuery from 1.0 to 2.0 I wasn't including the micro releases inbetween 1.6 & 1.7 for example. Testing 1.6.1 etc. was what I was missing, and was of course the problem. Anybody else having the same problem should check all subreleases.

Comment: If possible use the jquery 1.6.4 release as it contains the latest bugfixes for the 1.6 release.  The other versions 1.5, 1.7, etc... usually have added funcionalities which is why they did not work for you...